# Elasticsearch raise in fetch time

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

after small update I noticed a bad trend on elasticsearch performance (see the image).
What seems to cause the problem is a "denormalization" procedure, that updates a subset of the documents every hour.
My suggestion is, that the rise of fetch time is caused by document updates.

Do you know of any solution, to avoid/mitigate this behavior?

[image: ES performance]